# Shorten a join query

Tags: mysql

I have a query with 3 joins:

```
SELECT t1.email, t2.firstname, t2.lastname, t4.value
FROM t1
left join t2 on t1.email = t2.email
Inner join t3 on t2.entity_id = t3.order_id
Inner join t4 on t3.product_id = t4.entity_id
WHERE t4.attribute_id = 126
```

I think my server just can't make it :) --> time is running out so an error occurs!

Thanks a lot

Table structur:

T1:
email (which is the same then in t2)

T2: 
email firstname lastname orderid (which is called entity id in t3)

T3:
entityid product id (which is called entity id in t4)

T4:
entityid attributeid value

Comment: Could you post your table structures?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Running time too long?  We assume all the `*_id` fields are proper PKs and FKs with defined relationships.  Do you have an index on `t1.email`?

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you getting an error?  Is the query not returning the results you expect?  If not, what are the results and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: Of course, it can't. You select from **t**.email, but then write **t1**

Answer (score 1):

Unless t2 links straight to t4 there is no way.

Also, do you need a left join between t1 and t2?

Comment: They do link with the given words. And the left join is because in t1 are more people than in t2 and I need all of them.

Comment: Look, if you outer join t1 to t2, it means don't lose anything from t1 if there happens to be no match in t2. So there could be NULL rows in t2. And then you inner join t2 to t3. That does not make sense, since any Null rows in t2 will never match rows in t3.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sachin already stated, you can't "shorten" this query unless `t2` links **straight** to `t4` without requiring a comparison with `t3`. However, in order to speed up your query, you should have indexes on some or all of the columns referenced in your join conditions (i.e. `t1.email`, `t2.email`, `t2.entity_id`, etc).

Having an index on each of these columns will give you much faster `SELECT` queries, but it will slow down your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries. So if you `SELECT` more often than you `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, then you should definitely be using indexes. If not, try to make indexes in wise places (tables that have `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements run less often but still have a lot of rows, for instance).

For further clarification, see the following links:

[More information on how indexes work](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

[Syntax for creating indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try your query this way:

```
SELECT t1.email, t2.firstname, t2.lastname, t4.value
FROM t4
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.product_id = t4.entity_id
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.entity_id = t3.order_id
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t4.attribute_id = 126
```

It's basically your query but "backwards".  Your original way, your DBMS has to try to join `t2` for ALL records in t1, then join `t3` for ALL records found in t2 before it can even attempt to address your `WHERE` clause.

My way, you're finding all the records in `t4` where `attribute_id = 126` first, THEN attempting to join other tables.  It should be a lot quicker.  You should then be able to speed things up even more by making sure the proper indexes exist on the tables involved.  You can prepend the keyword `EXPLAIN` to your query to see how the DBMS attempts to seek data in your query.